# Get Kendo Grid filtered datasource count

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I'm using tool bar filter Dropdown in kendo grid. When user selects the dropdown I need to get the count of filtered records. Below code is not working for me

```
function ExamDateChange() { // function on dropdown change
        var value = this.value(),
             grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

        if (value) {
            grid.dataSource.filter({ field: "ExamID", operator: "eq", value: value });

            grid.dataSource.fetch(function () {
                var view = dataSource.view();
                alert(view.length); 

            });

        } else {

            grid.dataSource.filter({});
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You might use fetch but instead of using `dataSource.view().length` you should use `dataSource.total()` method.

Something like:

```
function ExamDateChange() { // function on dropdown change
    var value = this.value(),
        grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");    
    if (value) {
        grid.dataSource.filter({ field: "ExamID", operator: "eq", value: value });
        grid.dataSource.fetch(function () {
            alert(view.dataSource.total()); 
        });
    } else {
        grid.dataSource.filter({});
    }
}
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/f19k0vrt/5/ Type two dates and click "Filter" button and it will apply the filter on Birth Date and show you the total.

Answer (score 2):

Okay here we go,
i tried also the chage event from the dropdown but it doesnt work as you said.
The event is called before the dataSource of the Grid is set.

So I think we need the callback when Grids dataSource is bound, so thaht the dataBound event from the Grid.

```
...
dataBound: function(){
    console.log("Grid data bound");   
    // this should do the trick    
    alert(grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data().length);
},
...
```

Here is a rudimental [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpmnj2gr/1/) of that.
I hope this is what you need.

**Update:**
In the case you use serverpaging, you could use the requestEnd event from the datasource.
You have to look up the server response. In the fiddle you got a "__count" property.
Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpmnj2gr/5/)

```
...
requestEnd: function (e) {
    var response = e.response;
    var type = e.type;
    alert(response.d.__count); // displays "77"
},
...
```

Comment: Hello! thanks for the answer but the code returns the count of a single page. It doesn't work when the paging is enabled